The reciprocal of the normalized tail of the Maclaurin power series expansion of the hyperbolic sinc function is a convex function
The classical Bernoulli numbers $B_j$ are generated by
\begin{equation}\label{Bernoulli-No-Generating}
\frac{x}{\operatorname{e}^x-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty B_j\frac{x^j}{j!}=1-\frac{x}2+\sum_{j=1}^\infty B_{2j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!}, \quad 0<|x|<2\pi.
\end{equation}
From the series expansion
\begin{equation}\label{log-sin-series-expansion}
\ln\sin x=\ln x+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^j\frac{2^{2j-1}}{j}B_{2j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!}, \quad 0<x<\pi
\end{equation}
on Page 55 in the handbook

I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, Table of Integrals, Series, and
Products, Translated from the Russian, Translation edited and with a
preface by Daniel Zwillinger and Victor Moll, Eighth edition, Revised
from the seventh edition, Elsevier/Academic Press, Amsterdam, 2015;
available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-384933-5.00013-8

we can derive the Maclaurin power series expansion
\begin{equation}\label{F(x)-ser-expan-rew}
\ln\frac{\sinh x}{x}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2j-1}}{j}B_{2j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!}, \quad |x|<\pi.
\end{equation}
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, define
\begin{equation}\label{Tail-F(x)frak-Dfn}
\mathfrak{T}_n(x)=
\begin{cases}\displaystyle
\frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}}\frac{1}{B_{2n+2}} \frac{(2n+2)!}{x^{2n+2}} \Biggl[\ln\frac{\sinh x}{x}-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{2^{2j-1}}{j}B_{2j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!}\Biggr], & x\ne0;\\
1, & x=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We call the quantity $\mathfrak{T}_n(x)$ the normalized tail of the Maclaurin power series expansion of the hyperbolic sinc function
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{sinhc} x=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sinh x}{x}, & x\ne0;\\
1, & x=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Problem. Prove that the reciprocal $\dfrac{1}{\mathfrak{T}_n(x)}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a convex function of $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Motivations and Backgrounds. The idea proposing this problem is similar to the one in another problem at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4946469. As for the concept of normalized tails, please refer to the following three papers.
Related References

D.-W. Niu and F. Qi, Monotonicity results of ratios between normalized tails of Maclaurin power series expansions of sine and cosine, Mathematics 12 (2024), no. 12, Article 1781, 20 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/math12121781.
G.-Z. Zhang, Z.-H. Yang, and F. Qi, On normalized tails of series expansion of generating function of Bernoulli numbers, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. (2024), in press; available online at https://doi.org/10.1090/proc/16877.
T. Zhang, Z.-H. Yang, F. Qi, and W.-S. Du, Some properties of normalized tails of Maclaurin power series expansions of sine and cosine, Fractal Fract. 8 (2024), no. 5, Art. 257, 17 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/fractalfract8050257.

